# How do I write a constructor that initializes 52 card objects

Tags: java

This is what I need to do:

This constructor initializes the Deck with 52 card objects, representing the 52 cards that are in a standard deck.  The cards must be ordered from ace of spades to king of diamonds.

Here is my attempt at it:

```
private Card[] cards;
String suit, card;
private final int DECK_SIZE = 52;

public Deck() 
{
    cards = new Card[DECK_SIZE];
    String suit[] = {"spades", "hearts", "clovers", "diamonds"};
    String card[] = {"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Joker", "Queen", "King"};
    for (int c = 0; c<13; c++)
        for (int s = 0; s<4; s++)
        {
            cards.equals(new Card(suit, card));

        }



}
```

It is giving me an error for this part "(new Card(suit, card));" saying constructor Card(String[], String[]) is undefined.  Im not sure if we are allowed to add extra constructors.  The code written for us does include a Card(int, int) though.

Ok what about this?  Would this work?

```
public class Deck {

    private Card[] cards;
    int value, suit;
    private final int DECK_SIZE = 52;

    public Deck() 
    {
        //1 = Ace, 11=joker, 12=queen, 13=king
        //1 = spades, 2 = hearts, 3 = clovers, 4 =diamonds
        cards = new Card[DECK_SIZE];
        int suit[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
        int card[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13};
        for (int c = 0; c<13; c++)
            for (int s = 0; s<4; s++)
            {
                cards.equals(new Card(suit[s], card[c]));

            }

        }
```

Comment: It may be a better method to treat the cards as numbers (1-13) and do the text replacements for Ace, Jack, Queen, and King on display.

Comment: "`constructor Card(String[], String[]) is undefined.`" tells it all.  You are giving it suit and card.  They are defined as `String suit[]` and `String card[]`.  They are both String arrays.  Is this really what you want to make a card out of?

Comment: No, the better method is to talk to the instructor that gave you the assignment to better understand how to use their Card class.

Comment: See also this [example](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to create a deck of cards constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592817/how-to-create-a-deck-of-cards-constructor)

Comment: Closed as not a real question, possible duplicate... Come on people this is someone who is still learning who is pretty close to getting something working, but is missing some last pieces of info. If you find it 'difficult to tell what is being asked here' then you don't know Java. I looked at the question for just a couple of seconds and instantly understood his intent *and* spotted the error of passing the whole arrays instead of the element at the current index... But why spend time providing an answer? Better spend it downvoting newbies right?? StackOverflow what's happening to you??!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
cards = new Card[DECK_SIZE];
String suits[] = {"spades", "hearts", "clovers", "diamonds"};
String cards[] = {"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Joker", "Queen", "King"};

int cardIndex = 0;
for (String suit : suits) {
    for (String card : cards) {
        cards[cardIndex] = new Card(suit, card);
        cardIndex++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Im not sure if we are allowed to add extra constructors. The code written for us does include a Card(int, int) though.

Only your instructor or TA can answer that. We are not omniscient.

As for your current version:

Are you sure you want to make a `Card` with a list of suits and card types?

Even if the constructor were to exist, I don't think `.equals` does what you think it does. I would consult the documentation on this matter.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the bad use of `.equals`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your equals method does, but you are passing in the full array. Try this...

```
cards.equals(new Card(suit[s], card[c]));
```